# Approach in migrating Access rows to existing SQL tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, migration

I have used SSMA 5.2 to migrate an Access 2010 database to SQL 2005 (SP3). The SQL database is part of an ASP.NET application and is currently in production. However, users have also been inserting new records into the tables of the original Access file and now I need to insert these new rows into the SQL tables. There are around 100+ tables.

Unfortunately, If I try to run SSMA again, it requires that I overwrite the SQL tables. If I do this I will loose the new rows that have been added, into the SQL tables, after the system went live. I only need to insert the new rows that are in Access.

Are there any other tools available that I can use?

Appreciate if someone could help me resolve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SSMA to migrate the Access DB to a sencond SQL2005, using exactly the same procedure.
Afterwards, you can write a script that merges each table from each db.